# The difference between 最高 and 一番いい

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is the difference between 最高 and 一番いい? Both mean the best. But they should be used in different situations. What would be the right use of the words? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, **最高** means "the best" with a nuance of "an awesome thing". So you could say something like :

> 今日{きょう}のごはんは最高{さいこう}！昨日{きのう}のごはんも最高{さいこう}だったけどね。The food today, it's awesome/amazing/the best! The food yesterday was also awesome/amazing/the best though.

最高 is saying that, let's say, on a scale of 1 to 10, this thing is very close to 10. But not ranking things against each other like 1st or 2nd place. It just means that things are really good.

Now **一番いい** comes with a nuance of **ranking**, because it literally means **"The number 1 good thing"**

So, in my opinion, while casually saying the following sentence might be ok, it would be a little less "logical":

> このゲームが一{いち}番{ばん}いいなあ！そのゲームも一{いち}番{ばん}いいけどね。- This game is The number 1! That game is also The number 1 though.